# How long would it take to brute force a URL path that's 5 characters long

Tags: brute-force, url

`example.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]` the code can be any mix of numbers + uppercase/lowercase letters and it's 5 characters. How long would it take to brute force or is there an easier/faster way to do it?

Comment: The number of tries you need at most is simple math: 62^5. On average you'll find a hit after half the maximum. But how long this takes depends on how fast the server responds and if it employs measures against brute-forcing, i.e. can not be said based on your information.

Answer (score 0):

This wont take much long but as mention by @steffen  it depends on the server response if your server is responding fast  then i could suggest with gobuster it will take maximum five hours with all possible combination. use atleast 50 threads.

```
gobuster -u https://examplecom -w your-wordlist  -t 50
```

generate the combination first and then give it to go buster it will complete with five hours.